# Moving vertex without moving adjacent edges

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I draw this graph with Tikz but I don't like how the edges leave {e}: [image]

It would be perfect, if I could move the vertex {e} a little bit to the left *withuot* moving its adjacent edges, so that it looks more like in vertex {a}.  Any ideas?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={rectangle,draw=black,thick}]
\node(a)at(-2,1){\(\{a\}\)};
\node(b1)at(0,0){\(\{b_0\}\)};
\node(b0)at(0,2){\(\{b_1\}\)};
\node(c1)at(2,0){\(\{c_0\}\)};
\node(c0)at(2,2){\(\{c_1\}\)};
\node(d1)at(5,0){\(\{d_3,\hdots,d_9\}\)};
\node(d0)at(5,2){\(\{d_0,\hdots,d_2\}\)};
\node(e)at(8,1){\(\{e\}\)};
\draw(a)to[bend left=30](b0);
\draw(a)to[bend right=30](b1);
\draw(e)to[bend right=20](d0);
\draw(e)to[bend left=20](d1);
\draw(b0)--(c0)--(d0)--(d1)--(c1)--(b1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not the node {e} that should be moved, it is the entrance of the edge in {e}. You can specify this by e.g.

```
\draw(e.north)to[bend right=20](d0);
\draw(e.south)to[bend left=20](d1);
```

which gives

[image]

You can also give the position as an angle, like in

```
\draw(e.90)to[bend right=20](d0);
\draw(e.-90)to[bend left=20](d1);
```

which gives the same picture.

If you also want to change the angle of which the edge is starting you can, apart from `[bend right=<angle>]` give different angles for in and out, as in

```
\draw(e.north)to[out=90,in=0](d0);
\draw(e.south)to[out=-90,in=0](d1);
```

[image]

In this case the positioning `e.north` and `e.south` does not make any difference, but with some different settings of the line angles it will. (Then it might also look better than this example.)